# How to Switch Parameter Type

Tags: c#, reflection

I have Method1, Method2, and Method3.

Method1 returns Type int.
Method2 returns Type string.

While Method3 takes a parameter of int or string, based on the return type of method1 or method2.

```
public void Method3 (ParameterType parm) { logic... }
```

The problem is: 
How to switch the passed ParameterType based on the Types of Method1 and Method2. This is of course a simplified version of the problem. In fact, there are many methods that return values of different types. Based on the current called method, for example Method1, how to extract its type, and then replace the ParameterType of Method3 with the new type.

Comment: Please show sample of how your code looks like generics or overloading as show in answers may be solution, but it is not exactly clear what "Based on the current called method" means.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  Unfortunately, I don't have access to the code right this moment. However, in the real world, this an ASP.NET MVC App. Methods3 is an Action Method, and each time a user clicks a menu item, I take that name extract from it a name of a method (Method1 or Method2) that matches an Entityframework Method of specific type that could be anything. So, all I need to feed that Action Method is The EF MethodName and its Type. That is the whole story. I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be able to define a generic method, e.g.

```
public void Method3<T>(T parm)
{
    // ...
}
```

You simply call the method and pass an argument and the type of that argument fixes `T` for that call.  That means that `T` can be any type though, so the code inside the method must use `parm` in ways that will work for any type.

You can apply certain constraints to a generic type parameter, e.g. that it must be or inherit a particular class, must implement a particular interface or must have a parameterless constructor.  There's no constraint that's going to work for both `int` and `string` though.

If you can't write common code for all types that may be passed as an argument then a single generic method is not an option.  You would have to overload the method and write two or more generic and/or non-generic methods with parameters that cover the gamut of types you want to be able to accept, e.g.

```
public void Method3<T>(T parm) where T : class
{
    // ...
}

public void Method3(int parm)
{
    // ...
}

public void Method3(double parm)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called *overloading*:

```
public void Method3 (int parm) { logic... }

public void Method3 (string parm) { logic... }


public void Foo(){
    Method3(Method1());
    Method3(Method2());
}
```